# How to get page scrolling position (y axis)

Tags: javascript

How can i get the current scrolling position of my browser?, i want to fire events base on page position.This is what I tried:

```
var scroll_position=document.viewport.getScrollOffsets();

window.onscroll = function (event) {

if(scroll_position>1000)
{
alert('xxxxxxxxxxx');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're always going to be testing with `window`, you can use [`window.scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollY):

```
window.onscroll = function (event) 
{
    if(this.scrollY > 1000)
    {
        alert('xxxxxxxxxxx');
    }
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2xf4/)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
window.onscroll = function (event) {
  if (window.scrollY > 1000) {
    alert('xxxxxxxxxxx');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As hsz said, do

```
window.onscroll = function (event) {
var scroll_position = document.viewport.getScrollOffsets();
if (scroll_position > 1000)
{
    alert('xxxxxxxxxxx');
}
}
```

The problem with your code:

```
var scroll_position=document.viewport.getScrollOffsets();
```

`scroll_position` is only set once, when the page loads - therefore it stays the same (probably 0) and the alert never comes up because `scroll_position` is less than 1000.

hsz put the statement that sets `scroll_position` into the window.onscroll function, so it is updated every time the page scrolls.

Comment: Why not just use `this.scrollY` inside the callback?

Comment: there are always different solutions. i have upvoted your answer - it does work.